# Nginx if operators

Tags: variables, nginx, lua, webserver, openresty

Good morning programmers, I'm trying to protect a file, and for that I'm checking the http_referer that is opening it. Example:

```
if ($http_referer != "stackoverflow.com") {
    return 403;
}
```

So far so good, this sentence works well, in this case I don't want the equal operator but I want the contain operator like "!~", so I turned it into:

```
if ($http_referer !~ "stackoverflow.com") {
    return 403;
}
```

Still, it works well too, but in order to make everything run flawless I need to use variables on the string like this:

```
set $website stackoverflow.com;
if ($http_referer != $website) {
    return 403;
}
```

The issue here is that I can use variables with the "!=" operator but it doesn't work with the "!~" in this case the sentence I gave works, but this sentence down here doesn't work:

```
set $website stackoverflow.com;
if ($http_referer !~ $website) {
    return 403;
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

**P.S: if you don't get the if, you can't open the file if your http referer doesn't contain "stackoverflow.com"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't use variables inside the regex patterns in the nginx config. I think that's because they are compiled at the nginx startup. General solution for this is to use the [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) block:

```
map $http_referer $valid_value {
    ~stackoverflow\.com    1;
}
```

and then check the resulting variable value:

```
if ($valid_value != 1) {
    return 403;
}
```

But for checking exactly the `Referer` HTTP header value there exists a special [`valid_referers`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html#valid_referers) directive where you can use a regular expression(s):

```
valid_referers ~stackoverflow\.com;
if ($invalid_referer) {
    return 403;
}
```